# Not able to install anything in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package, installation, ubuntu-18.04, uninstallation, java-11

Whenever i try to install anything, i encounters something like this which prohibits it from installing...

```
E: The package oracle-java11-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```